# golang Assigning a value to an existing element in a slice of slices (2d slice)

Tags: go, 2d, slice

I have a slice which is composed of slices of type string.   I would like to be able to assign values to individual elements of this slice of slices, not necessarily in sequence.  Then, later, I would like to be able to change the value of any particular element.  I have read the posts on this same question with slices, but I can't figure out how to apply this to slices of slices.  Consider this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type aRow []string
type aGrid struct {
    col []aRow
}

func main() {
    var c aGrid
    r := make(aRow, 4) // each row will have 4 elements
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        c.col = append(c.col, r) // there will be 3 rows
    }
    i, j := 1, 2
    c.col[i][j] = "i=" + strconv.Itoa(i) + "  j=" + strconv.Itoa(j)

    fmt.Println("c= ", c)
    // c=  {[[  i=1  j=2 ] [  i=1  j=2 ] [  i=1  j=2 ]]}
}
```

I want to assign the string to jth element of the ith slice of c, but it assigns the string to jth element of every slice of c.

I've tried getting to the backing value of the inner slice, like

```
i, j := 1, 2
    c.col[i][j].value = "i=" + strconv.Itoa(i) + "  j=" + strconv.Itoa(j)

//  yields "c.col[i][j].value undefined (type string has no field or method value)"
```

and pointers like

```
    p := &c.col[i][j]
    p.value = "i=" + strconv.Itoa(i) + "  j=" + strconv.Itoa(j)

// yields "p.value undefined (type *string has no field or method value)"
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: The application creates a single row and assigns it to all columns.  Create new row for each column by moving the statement `r := make(aRow, 4)` inside the for loop.

Comment: If you don't mind , can you provide the expecting output too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the same row `r` for every column.

```
c.col = append(c.col, r)
```

So, every column's has same row `r` that why set in one row means set in every row.

Create new row for every column.

```
for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    r := make(aRow, 4) // each row will have 4 elements
    c.col = append(c.col, r) // there will be 3 rows
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This filled in a significant gap in my understanding.